# Как в веб-форму Битрикс загрузить данные из инфоблока?

Tags: битрикс

В веб-форме есть выпадающий список (пока пустой), в который нужно загрузить список подрядчиков из определенного инфоблока.

Как это можно сделать средствами Битрикс?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в result_modifier.php сделать GetList вытащить нужные данные и добавить в результирующий массив для вывода в шаблоне, а далее foreach по данным в нужном месте.

Что кстати за компонент?

Comment: @Taarim компонент form.

Comment: а куда положить этот файл? компонент перенес в /bitrix/components/med-service/form

Comment: @Cергей - form, который комплексный?

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2830&LESSON_PATH=3913.4565.2830

Кладется данный файл в папку с шаблоном, который вы используете. В частности если это комплексный компонент, то в шаблон того компонента, в котором нужен вывод данных

Comment: добавил файл, выбрал данные из нужного инфоблока. А как добавить их в результирующий массив?

Comment: и как это все увязать с формой?

Comment: $arResult['CUSTOM_DATA'] = данные из гетлиста (ключ может быть каким угодно).

И в шаблоне формы работаете с $arResult['CUSTOM_DATA']

Comment: уже ближе) Не могу только понять, как заполнить выпадающий список, там ведь (в шаблоне) выводятся вопросы циклом из настроек формы и непонятно где какие поля.

Comment: а тип поля "привязка к элементам инфоблока" отсутсвует разве?

Comment: добавил скрин. Тут оно есть?

Comment: в общем, через шаблон формы при помощи костыля (if ($arQuestion['STRUCTURE'][0]['ID'] == 71)) удалось подменить нужный селект своим, но в результаты формы значение его не попадает, хотя прописал и name и id оригинала. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: В таких случая лучше всего делать форму на основе инфоблоков. И проблем никаких нет. Есть все нужные типы полей. Ничего не надо подменять и все без проблем добавляется. Уже давно все делают формы на инфоблоках, а не этим ущербным сервисом.

Comment: Можно ссылку на документацию?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению модуль "Веб-форм" не поддерживает работу со свойствами инфоблока. Реализовать данную задачу можно если реализовать форму через Инфоблоки. Для этого создайте инфоблок поля и свойства которого будут вопросами формы. Для нужного вам поля вы сможете указать "Привязка к элементу инфоблока". После этого в публичной части подключите комплексный компонент "[Добавление элемента инфоблока](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/adding/iblock_element_add.php)" и в его настройках укажите какие свойства выводить для заполнения пользователю. Результаты заполнения такой формы будут отображаться в качестве элементов данного инфоблока.